# How can I setup end-to-end, secure communication between two Windows processes over an Active Directory network?

Tags: c#, security, active-directory, .net-3.5

I have a service that runs on a server.  It deploys an executable to a client and launches the application. After the application launches on the client, the application needs to request sensitive information from the host.

Here's the problem. Obviously, I could have some secure communications channel established between my client and my server host using TLS.  However, if we assume the possibility that there is an exploit/bot running on the client machine, we could assume that the attacking software could spoof the client application and make a similar request to the host using the TLS channel and acquire the sensitive information.

I understand that if an attacker is already on a client machine, that's a HUGE problem.  However, there is no way of knowing if this is the case and I need to operate under the assumption that if it is possible, we must put forth every possible barrier to prevent the exploit from accessing this sensitive data.

Within two separate .Net applications running on two different Active Directory devices, how can I establish some form of secure communication channel between these two processes, guaranteeing that the communication between the them are originating from the expected processes/application binaries?

I also have a requirement for backwards compatibility reasons, that this needs to be done using .Net 3.5 (or earlier) libraries since our tool is used across a very wide range of Windows environments.

Comment: So you're concerned that a bot on the client machine could surreptitiously spoof an active TLS session?

Comment: Theoretically, yes.

Comment: @user8675309 I know that may sound crazy, but we have a very hard requirement that we verify that a process running on a machine is, in fact, the source of the communication to the host. In other words, it's not enough to verify that communication is coming from a specific device, we need to know that the process we kicked off is the one communicating back to our application and not some other process that wakes up and initiates a secure channel and spoofs the other applications data requests.